# Does this experiment on wave-particle duality and complementarity disprove quantum mechanics and prove the EPR viewpoint on it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-entanglement, double-slit-experiment

I recently read

> [*Photons act like they go through two paths, even when we know which they took*](http://arstechnica.com/science/2012/05/disentangling-the-wave-particle-duality-in-the-double-slit-experiment/), at Ars Technica,

which reports on the paper

> Wave-particle dualism and complementarity unraveled by a different mode. R. Menzel et al. [*PNAS* **109** (2012), 9314](http://dx.doi.org/10.1073/pnas.1201271109).

Please refer the Ars Technica link and its conclusion.

I am an Engineer. What I infer from this is :-

1. This proves ERP.
2. Einstein Wins.
3. This basically proves that quantum mechanics is incomplete/incorrect.
4. There is a requirement for an extension for QM.

What this does is :

1. "Declaration of completeness of quantum mechanics" by Heisenberg needs to be pulled down officially
2. Other theories needs to be thought about, like Bohm's.

> Can somebody confirm my understanding ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://www.pnas.org/content/early/2012/05/23/1201271109.full.pdf+html : the original paper.

Comment: It appears the original paper is in full agreement with quantum mechanics. Since they use entangled pairs it's not the traditional double slit experiment. It's far more likely that your interpretation is in error.

Comment: but if we know what path it took + we see interference. proves ERP. How am I interpreting this wrongly ?

Comment: No, that is not true. There is interference in another channel. Relevant quote: "We employ the entanglement...to obtain by a coincidence measurement of the two photons which-slit information about the signal photon without ever touching it....we observe in a separate coincidence experiment interference fringes in the signal photon...." (continues below)

Comment: "The explanation of this puzzling experimental observation springs from the transverse mode structure of the pump with two intensity maxima that creates a superposition of two macroscopically distinguishable wave vectors of the signal photon. In the case of a Gaussian pump with a single maximum no such superposition arises." In other words - they were clever enough to make an experiment which obeys ordinary quantum mechanics perfectly well, but violates the commonly used slogans and shows them to be too sloppy and inaccurate.

Comment: hmm, I will have to read about the "pumps". So apparently, you are saying that their sloppy experiment methodology lead to violation on complementary ?

Comment: @user1813004 the sloppy experiments  are the long list of traditional ones. The measurement of the path to determine the slit was such as to in reality create new boundary conditions for the photons/electrons/neutrons.

Comment: No, I'm not saying it was sloppy at all (though I'm not qualified to comment, really, being a theoretician). I'm saying they cleverly designed the experiment to have more than one interference channel. This shows that the naive slogans about complementarity don't completely capture the reality of quantum interference. This is no surprise to someone who has used quantum scattering theory, but it often gets passed over in popular treatments.

Comment: Ok. If it is not difficult, would anybody link to websites/forums where "This" paper is discussed in depth. I want to sort this out, non-deterministic universe bugs me :)

Comment: @user1813004 No, the experimentalists methodology was not sloppy, it is the science journalists and the slogans they use that are sloppy. There is probably a deeper and more important point for you to take on board, which is that EPR's argument has already been proven wrong beyond all reasonable doubt. Reason being, EPR assumed *local realism*, which was shown by Bell and Aspect to be a false assumption, see [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell's_theorem).

Comment: Should mention two other things: First, there is active research in the field of quantum foundations where people take alternatives to quantum mechanics seriously. So far none of these has gained traction since so far no experiment has reproducibly violated quantum mechanics. If one day such an experiment turned up there is a community of physicists there already to take up the challenge. Second, Bohmian mechanics (which I actually like), would agree with this experiment since *all* of its predictions are identical to those of standard quantum mechanics. :)

Comment: And here is a scienceblog article, which discusses the experiment on a somewhat higher level: http://scienceblogs.com/principles/2012/06/04/single-photons-are-still-photons-wave-particle-dualism-and-complementarity-unraveled-by-a-different-mode/

Answer (score 0):

In my answer to [wave-particle duality](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53959/wave-particle-duality/53970#53970) I expain the key to this misunderstanding in popular expositions on quantum mechanics.

The basic problem is that people think that the wave nature of the elementary particle entity, is exhibited in its mass distribution. They think that the entity is spread out in space according to the wave function of the quantum mechanical solution. **It is the probability of finding the particle at (x,y,z,t) that is predicted by the quantum mechanical solutions.**

When one looks at a probability curve, for example the  life expectancy as a function of current age, one does not see oneself spreading out in fractions or continually until 100 years. One knows that it is just a probability distribution derived by the census bureau. It is the same with the quantum mechanical probability distributions ( the square of the wave function). The experiment you link to is just a smarter experiment than the traditional "check the slit" experiments which introduced large distortion to the measurements and created the artifact of a spread particle magically gathering itself up.