# Wave-like properties of particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wave-particle-duality, wavelength

If we consider a particle such as an electron to have wave-like properties too, what kind of wave it is? What is exactly meant by its wavelength?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wave-particle duality](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53959/)