# Is there any proof particles really exist?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, wavefunction, wave-particle-duality

Maybe is a dumb question, but I was always confused about the wave-particle duality, what if particles are just an interpretation of our brains? is that possible? that everything is actually a wave, and in just scenarios those waves acts like our concept of particle?

Asking it in another way: do we need particles? as a real thing? or the universe could be just waves and nothing else?

Comment: Related and possibly a duplicate: [Do photons truly exist in a physical sense or are they just a useful concept like $i = \sqrt{-1}$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/303132/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do photons truly exist in a physical sense or are they just a useful concept like $i = \sqrt{-1}$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/303132/)

Comment: Have a look in my  answer to a similar question here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53959/wave-particle-duality/53970#53970  also at this bubble chamber picture  http://cds.cern.ch/record/39471?ln=en

Comment: Quantum mechanical entities are called particles because they leave a footprint like a classical particle, see the single electron at a time double slit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles  . It is only in accumulation of observations of particles with the same energy in the same boundry conditions that the wave nature appears.

Comment: What is the difference between "exist" and "really exist"?

Comment: @WillO I mean if we can create a mahematical model with only waves, without requiring the concept of "particle" anywhere (or what is the same describe the concepto of particle as some type of wave, like wave packet etc)

Comment: @Enrique It should be the other way around. You can explain or derive any phenomenon with a particle theory but wave theory only explains some.

Comment: This paper may be of interest: [“There are no particles, there are only fields”](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.4616)

Comment: The fundamental objects in any quantum field theory are, of course, quantum fields. Particles are just excitations of the fields.

Comment: @G.Smith the “fields” are billions of coherent photons (particles).

Comment: @Enrique The concept of particle, even elementary particle, comes from nature. Look at the bubble chamber pictures and tell me if those are not the traces of what we would call classical particles, like a sand particle. https://hst-archive.web.cern.ch/archiv/HST2005/bubble_chambers/BCwebsite/index.htm . I was writing an answer on those lines when the question was made duplicate. Also the single electron spots on the screen shout "particle"

Comment: and please understand that the wave nature of quantum mechanicae entities is not in space and time, but in the **probability** of being at  a spot in space and time.. i.e the probability for the electron in the double slit experiment to be at the specific (x,y) of the screen

Comment: @BillAlsept That isn’t true according to mainstream physics.

Comment: @G.Smith So if the field is not made up of coherent photons then what? It is possible to build a particle theory but the light wave theory has nothing to back it. No one even tries to offer a physical description. You might as well say spiritual theory, because it relies on faith.

Comment: @BillAlsept Quantum field theory — which, as the name says, is a theory of quantum *fields* — is an extremely accurate and well-verified physical theory that has absolutely nothing to do with spiritualism or faith. It explains particles and their behavior without particles being the fundamental objects of the theory. QFT is, in fact, the basis for the Standard Model of mainstream particle physics.

Comment: @G.Smith you are right QM absolutely explains particles. It’s light waves that have no explanation. Just saying light wave doesn’t make it something real. You need to at least make an attempt to describe what it is. On the other hand particle theories explain and derive everything. Why kick the can down the road with this unaccountable idea of light waves when you have particles. QM math IS the math of a particle theory. And more importantly you can describe a particle theory but you cannot describe a light wave  theory. Where would you begin without photons.

Comment: @BillAlsept I only discuss mainstream physics, and comments are not the place to have discussions, so I am not going to respond further.

Comment: @G.Smith yeah that’s usually the response. Thanks anyway But for the record you haven’t discussed main stream ideas because you haven’t explain what a lightwave is and you can’t.